# how to change the option container of a select

Tags: html, css

I have a select and I would like to change the design of the options container, especially by changing it with rounded corners and removing the borders

```
       <select>
           <option val="0" selected></option>
           <option val="1"></option>
           <option val="2"></option>
           <option val="3"></option>
           <option val="4"></option>
           <option val="5"></option>
      </select>
```

I know the solution to change the style of the select and the options but I don't know how to change in css the options container

Comment: Rounded corners but no border? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I think its easier to write an own dropdown and call from js, dont need deep css

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `select` tag with CSS just like any other element:

```css
#select-1 {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0;
}

#select-2 {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <select id="select-1">
   <option val="0" selected>0</option>
   <option val="1">1</option>
   <option val="2">2</option>
   <option val="3">3</option>
   <option val="4">4</option>
   <option val="5">5</option>
 </select>

 <select id="select-2">
   <option val="0" selected>0</option>
   <option val="1">1</option>
   <option val="2">2</option>
   <option val="3">3</option>
   <option val="4">4</option>
   <option val="5">5</option>
 </select>
```

However, styling `select` or `option` tags is somewhat very limited. For example, changing the appearance of the dropdown arrow icon will be difficult. Furthermore, changing the style of the `option` container is not possible (or at least very limited).

State of the art would be to discard the HTML built-in component and write your own dropdown component ([example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp)).

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to style your select option.Here is one way

```
.custom-select {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```
   <select class="custom-select">
           <option val="0" selected>0</option>
           <option val="1">1</option>
           <option val="2">2</option>
           <option val="3">3</option>
           <option val="4">4</option>
           <option val="5">5</option>
      </select>
```